# Import a local package from another local package

Tags: go

My project structure is like this:

```
MicroService-Server (project name and folder) 
    main.go
    ---model(folder name)
    ------ package model
    ---logics (folder name)
    -----campaigncreation (folder name)
    --------package campaigncreation
    -----utilities (folder name)
    --------package utilities
    ---controller (folder name)
```

I want to use "model" package in "campaigncreation", I tried various import statements but I get error for all of them:

```
import (
    model "././model"
)

import (
    model "./model"
)

import (
    model "MicroService-Server/model"
)

import (
    model "./model"
)
```

Comment: Are you using go modules? And what's the path to your root `MicroService-Server`?

Comment: My root is MicroService-Server. Not sure what you mean by go modules? I am using  Go and inside each directory I have some-files.go which are containing "package" code like package model, package utilities, etc

Comment: Yes, I understand that's the root, I'm asking what is *the path to the root*. Is it `$GOPATH/src/MicroService-Server`?

Comment: No, it is inside a custom directory. D:\Go Projects\MicroService-Server, my Go installation folder is different.

Comment: Your go installation folder would be `$GOROOT`, not `$GOPATH`. If you're not using modules, your project must be under the Go workspace at `$GOPATH/src`. If you don't want it there, you'll need to use go modules. Go workspaces are covered [in the installation instructions](https://golang.org/doc/install#testing).

Answer (score 1):

Relative imports are highly discouraged in Go community. It makes the code vague and error prone.

You should import any custom package starting from the $GOPATH/src/....
So, if your MicroService-Server resides like $GOPATH/src/MicroService-Server/, then you can import model package in campaigncreation easily like this:

```
import "MicroService-Server/model"
```

Here's a catch, if your MicroService-Server folder is not inside the $GOPATH, you can not import it. For this purpose of portability, you should use vendoring tools like the official "go mod" or third party glide.